# Search Generic C# List with Contravariant Type

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list, contravariance

Imagine I have class like this:

```
class MyKey : IComparable<MyKey> {
    public int Key { get; private set; }
    public MyKey(int key) { Key = key; }
    public int CompareTo(MyKey that) {
        return that.Key - this.Key;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I have a generic wrapper class like this:

```
class MyListWrapper<T> where T : MyKey
{
    private List<T> list;

    public MyListWrapper(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        list = new List<T>(items);
        list.Sort();
    }

    public int Search(T searchKey)
    {
        return list.BinarySearch(searchKey);
    }
}
```

This allows people to store custom class inheriting from `MyKey`, and it works perfectly fine. However, it would also make sense to be able to search using a `MyKey` as we know `T` is a `MyKey`, and the list is sorted using `MyKey`'s `Key`:

```
public int Search(MyKey searchKey)
{
    return list.BinarySearch(searchKey); // Does not compile!
}
```

However, this doesn't compile, since `BinarySearch` takes a `T` (`T` could be any custom class).

Neither does it work, if I provide the comparer. Imagine `MyKey` wasn't comparable, but I made a custom comparer that used `Key` instead. I could use it when sorting and when searching.

Is is possible to search the list using `MyKey` somehow? I don't like storing the list as `List<MyKey>` and cast the values when I use them (that defeats the purpose of the generic list). I can't cast the list of type `List<T>` to `List<MyKey>` either.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper class which inherits from `MyNamedKey` or create new instance of `MyNamedKey` itself just to search the item.

```
var mySearchKey = new MyKey { Key = 2 };
var index = list.BinarySearch(new MyNamedKeyWrapper(mySearchKey));

class MyNamedKeyWrapper : MyNamedKey
{
    public MyNamedKeyWrapper(MyKey key)
    {
        this.Key = key.Key;
    }
}
```

This will help you to maintain O(log n) while adding small allocation cost.

Or if you prefer to use brittle reflection, you can.. Get the instance of underlying array and cast it to `MyKey[]` (This works because arrays are covariant) and use `Array.BinarySearch`.

```
var array = (MyKey[])list.GetType()
    .GetField("_items", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(list);
var index = Array.BinarySearch(array, mySearchKey);
```

Edit: Since you don't know the most derived type, if you constraint `new()` with your generic parameter, you can achieve what you're looking for

```
class MyListWrapper<T> where T : MyKey, new()
{
    private readonly List<T> list;
    public MyListWrapper(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        list = new List<T>(items);
        list.Sort();
    }

    public int Search(MyKey searchKey)
    {
        T dummyKey = new T() { Key = searchKey.Key };
        return list.BinarySearch(dummyKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use cast to MyKey, why not to use simple LINQ: `list.Cast<MyKey>()`?

Comment: @ArtemKulikov Linq cast is O(n) direct cast is O(1). Btw Linq Cast doesn't gives you an array, it just gives you an `IEnumerable<T>`, you need to convert it into an array or list.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one important aspect: I don't the type of MyNamedKey. I have updated the example to hopefully make my intentions more clear.

Comment: @lund.mikkel Second part of my answer will still work but it is brittle in a sense that when msft changes the name of the internal array from `_items` it will fail. Otherwise it should work

Comment: @lund.mikkel Updated my answer using `new()` constraint, see if that helps. It puts a restriction that you can use `T` as a type parameter only when it has a public parameterless constructor defined. My part2 and part3 of the answer will work for you.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Updated example again: I can't use the `new()` trick, and I can't set the key anywhere else than in the constructor. I have currently gotten it to work with the reflection solution, but I'm not a fan of it, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @lund.mikkel If you can't use `new` and reflection, you can inject a factory instance for creating `T`? I.e something like `Func<T>` in parameter so that you can create new instance of `T` inside your `Search` method? Otherwise, you're stuck with the reflection implementation I guess. I'm out of options.

Answer (score -3):

Linq is what you're after!

First, make sure you have `System.Linq` referenced in your usings.

Then you can use the following code to get all matching list items:

```
IEnumerable<MyNamedKey> found = list.Where(l => l.Key == 2);
```

To get a single item, use:

```
MyNamedKey found = list.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Key == 2);
```

Comment: This is linear operation hence O(n)

Comment: Yeah, the whole idea is to keep the search logarithmic.

Comment: Right you are, I misunderstood the requirements.